# Why would a Spring Batch Job not run every batch until completed?

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing

I am working on an existing service that runs a chunk oriented Spring Batch Job which is triggered by the Spring Scheduler. The job processes the records in batches of 25K. In my local environment, the job executes one batch after another until all the records are processed, as it is supposed to. However, in the QA environment, the Spring Job will read/process/write one batch and then sit idle until the next time the JobLauncher is triggered by the @Scheduled method.

```
    @Bean(name = "contactItemJob")
    Job contactItemJob(MultiJobCheckBatchListener multiJobCheckBatchListener) {
        return jobs.get("contactItemJob").start(contactItemStep()).listener(multiJobCheckBatchListener).build();
    }

private Step contactItemStep() {
        return steps.get("contactItemStep").<List<ScheduleResultSet>, List<Items>>chunk(1).faultTolerant()
                .skip(Exception.class).skipLimit(1).reader(scheduleItemReader()).processor(scheduleItemProcessor())
                .writer(scheduleItemWriter()).build();
    }
```

Since the problem is only in one environment, I assume that it must have something to do with the configuration. I compared the application.yaml's and the few fields related to Spring Batch were identical.

When I query the batch_step_execution table, the step has a status of STARTED as it should, and the step will be updated with the latest info each time the @Scheduled method triggers a new job. So that aspect works as expected.

What are the possible reasons that a Spring Batch Job would only complete 1 chunk at a time?